# MySQL query to find matching string using REGEXP not working

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using `MySQL 5.5`.

I have a table named `nutritions`, having a column `serving_data` with `text` datatype.

Some of the values in `serving_data` column are like:

```
[{"label":"1 3\/4 cups","unit":"3\/4 cups"},{"label":"1 cups","unit":"3\/4 cups"},{"label":"1 container (7 cups ea.)","unit":"3\/4 cups"}]
```

Now, I want to find records containing `serving_data` like `1 3\/4 cups` .

For that I've made a query,

```
SELECT id,`name`,`nutrition_data`,`serving_data`
FROM `nutritions` WHERE serving_data REGEXP '(\d\s\\\D\d\scup)+';
```

But is seems not working.

Also I've tried

```
SELECT id,`name`,`nutrition_data`,`serving_data`
FROM `nutritions` WHERE serving_data REGEXP '/(\d\s\\\D\d\scup)+/g';
```

If I use the same pattern in http://regexr.com/ then it seems matching.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` and `\D` with `[^0-9]` and `\s` with `[[:space:]]`. Try `WHERE serving_data REGEXP '([0-9]+[[:space:]])?[0-9]+/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+cup';`. See https://regex101.com/r/sO8fL3/1

Comment: Do not use `/.../g`. Use the pattern only. BTW, are the ``\`` really in the string, or not? I believe there are no ``\``s, right?

Comment: SELECT id,`name`,`nutrition_data`,`serving_data`
FROM `nutritions` WHERE serving_data REGEXP '[0-9][[:space:]]/[^0-9][0-9][[:space:]]cup'; - Seems not working. Yes ```\``` is there in the string.

Comment: If ``\`` is there, you need `REGEXP '([0-9]+[[:space:]]+)?[0-9]+\\\\/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+cup';` See https://regex101.com/r/sO8fL3/2

Comment: It seems working but the records like `[{"label":"1\/2 cup","unit":"cup"},{"label":"1 cup","unit":"cup"}]` are also gets selected with the said pattern. I want only records like `1 3\/4 cups` get selected with pattern.

Comment: Then remove the `?`-  `[0-9]+[[:space:]][0-9]+\\\\/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+cup`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Can you please post the answer that I can accept it and it might be useful to someone.

Comment: I added an answer below and described the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in MySQL regex, you cannot use shorthand classes like `\d`, `\D` or `\s`, replace them with `[0-9]`, `[^0-9]` and `[[:space:]]` respectively.

You may use

```
REGEXP '[0-9]+[[:space:]][0-9]+\\\\/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+cup'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO8fL3/4) (note that in general, regex101.com does not support MySQL regex flavor, but the PCRE option supports the POSIX character classes like `[:digit:]`, `[:space:]`, so it is only used for a demo here, not as a proof it works with MySQL `REGEXP`).

**Pattern details**:

- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `[[:space:]]` - a whitespace
- `[0-9]+`- 1 or more digits
- `\\\\/` - a literal `\/` char sequence
- `[0-9]+[[:space:]]+cup` - 1 or more digits, 1 or more whitespaces, `cup`.

Note that you may precise the word `cup` with a word boundary, add a `[[:>:]]` pattern after it to match a `cup` as a whole word.